# Finding alternate IC for 74HC245D

Tags: integrated-circuit, components, datasheet

I have built a PCB using IC 74HC245D for levelshifting 3.3v signal to 5v signal for RGB LEDs. But by mistake, I used TSSOP-20 footprint in my PCB, and while ordering parts I ordered a SOIC package so it's a mess as TSSOP IC is not easily available in India.

After a lot of searching, I got one IC that might work but I am confused that it will work with 5v or not. IC is 74LCX245MTCX datasheet says that it can tolerate up to 7V. The link for the datasheet is [Here](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/308/74LCX245_D-2310040.pdf).

[image]

But when I looked more into the datasheet I found it says the max is 3.6V so now I am confused, will it work with 5v or not?

[image]

Attaching my current schematic I am using 5v as Vcc.
[image]

Anyone here might have used this IC and can share some more info or any alter part that I can use.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: The 74LCX245MTCX is 5V tolerant, but it can't actively drive a 5V output. (Since it's not rated for Vcc = 5V.)

Comment: These are very easy to find 2nd source for since it's a standard IC. Different manufacturers might use different combinations of gibberish letters, 74LVC245, SN74LVC245 etc. This is because part numbers weren't decided by rational people back in the days. I very much doubt that you can't buy any part by any of the major silicon vendors. Far more likely, your purchase channels are bad.

Comment: Actually the HC type you were originally using would have been a mistake anyway. HC can't be used to level shift 3.3V inputs to 5V outputs.

Comment: Yes I know HC is not suited on paper but the vendor that I purchased IC from is in the business of addressable LEDs. They sell thousands of system that drives LEDs and he suggested the cheapest way to drive LED is this ic They have done intense testing to find it and use it on a daily basis.  Here is the website of seller https://www.teztech.in/

Comment: _"HC is not suited on paper"_ There you go. Please design with something which is suitable for your own sake. Using components out of spec is one of the most robust ways to have production problems and customer returns.

Comment: @winny  I agree with your design advice. I also agree with  the OP's note "They have done intense testing to find it and use it on a daily basis" in situations such as described. If the supplier is prepared to warrant the part in such use then they have effectively produced a relevant datasheet. ...

Comment: ...  I can show people how to use a TL431 in an operating area that is outside all datasheet's advice (but would usually be very careful about telling people about it  :-) ) BUT  which works for reasons that are obvious and always works.||  [Conversely - I've also written to Microchip pointing out that an application note violates their own device specifications in a way that I am certain will sometimes cause problems -  and they defended it!]

Comment: An 8 bit transceiver is an odd choice for a 4-bit level shifter.

Answer (score 4):

Staying inside the absolute maximum ratings guarantees that the device will not be damaged.
Staying inside the recommended operating conditions guarantees that the device will work correctly.

Neither the 74HC245 nor the 74LCX245 are guaranteed to be able to do the level shifting you want; the minimum V<sub>IH</sub> specification is above 3.3 V for a 5 V supply (and the 74LCX245 does not even specifiy it for 5 V).

To be able to input 3.3 V and output 5 V, you need a device with TTL-compatible inputs, e.g., from the HC**T** or AHC**T** logic families. So look for chips named (SN/CD)74HCT245, (SN)74AHCT245, or SN74LV8T245. You could also use unidirectional buffers with a similar footprint like (SN)74HCT541 or (SN)74AHCT541 if you pull pin 1 low.

---

Please note that unused inputs must never be left floating. Connect the A1/A3/A5/A7 pins to VCC or GND or a neighbouring input. (You could also use two channels in parallel for each LED to increase drive strength.)

Comment: Yes I read the datasheet and got that info, not to leave floating pins will be fixing that in V2. for now I can short them with solder to fix it not a big challenge on that.

Answer (score 1):

Over 30 000 devices in stock at Digikey. They ship all over the world, including India. Just place an order for the TSSOP-20 part and it will arrive.

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/buffers-drivers-receivers-transceivers/704?s=N4IgjCBcpgbFoDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbXABYBmAdgFZqQBdAgBwBcoQBlNgJwEsAdgHMQAXwLkI0EMkjps%2BIqRAAmAAyraATgbMQ7TjwEjxBVeQYy5C3AWKQyU2rQAc6pqw6RufIaIkQWksEWVRMO2VHNVcwKQ99Qx9jfzNwbVdtUJsIpQcyBMCAWnJs8MV7FTAwQoIi1TLIPgBXPJVaJmKs6ygWtuiIRjFhoA

Comment: Have already checked a few reasons not for ordering, will take more time to reach, high shipping and import duties.

Comment: @Dharmik Respin the board and use 5 V tolerant parts.

Comment: I'm afraid you keep trying to adjust the facts to fit your views, rather than the other way around. You seem to keep rewriting the question to one you wish it was. The OP made it clear from the start the problems they face with shipping. If it was that easy, they'd have done it already. Downvoting for that reason.

Comment: @TonyM What fact did I adjust? Do you mean Digikey does not ship to India?

Comment: It's all there already for you to read... (That's if you're accepting that the OP knows their situation considerably better from being in it, than you do knowing the bare minimum from a long way away.)

Comment: @TonyM I disagree. “Not easily available in India”. I could say the same about every component I use. I don’t have any local vendors for anything but THT resistors and it does not stop me or anyone else. It an XY question. Problem is X and instead of directly solving or addressing it, OP askes about potential locally available solution Y. I could not do my job if I limited myself to what’s available local and neither should OP.

Comment: Your taking the view that you understand the OP's situation better than they do and a glib 'delivers to India' covers everything. One of the frustrating things people can face when asking for assistance is someone trying to rewrite the question to how *they* see it and/or telling them they know the situation better than them who's actually in it. This continues to read like that in abundance, and I earlier noted that you appear to keep trying to adjust the facts to fit your views, rather than the other way around. I don't think we'll get anywhere with this we're both firm in our opinions.

Comment: @TonyM If I took that position that all my designs needs components which are locally available, I would be fired. Therefor, I had to bootstrap myself into EE'ing in 2023 which involves placing orders, deal with customs and paperwork. India isn't Iran or Ukraine as there is no trade embargo on them or ongoing warzone, and the boarders aren't closed.

Comment: I'm afraid that's just repetition of your same point and still without any attempt I can see to look into, understand or work forward from the position the OP has outlined. But good engineering's about thoroughly understanding the problem first then presenting a suitable answer, not the other way around. For example, you seem to have assumed that the OP is a professional engineer and that cost isn't an obstacle. For the latter, they've commented here that the costs are (too) high for them.

Comment: @TonyM I find no mention of cost or hobby project, but mistakes cost money to fix and I offered a solution. Feel free to choose a different one.

Answer (score -4):

I just wanted to extend my heartfelt thanks for all your fantastic suggestions and support.

After a lot of contemplation, I took a leap of faith and decided to give the 74LCX245MTCX IC a shot to see how it would mesh with my PCB design. I placed an order for the IC, soldered it onto one of my PCBs, and to my delight, it worked like a charm!

I'm excited to share that all the animations on my 1-meter LED strip, which has 96 LEDs per meter, are running incredibly smoothly. I plan to further put it to the test with a longer strip, and I'll be sure to keep you all posted.

[image]

Comment: OK, but you did not listen to the suggestions, or decided to ignore them. It is the wrong chip for 3.3V to 5V logic level conversion. It is not rated for 5V usage, only up to 3.6V, and manufacturer does not recommend exceeding the recommended operating conditions. It may work now, but it does not have to work at all, it may damage and even if this chip works it does not mean all other chips you buy will work.

Comment: *"I'll be sure to keep you all posted", "Stay tuned for more updates"* There can't be more updates, Dharmik. It's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum or your blog. As it's a Q&A site, this cannot be the answer to the question if it's not definitive and provable. Instead, you describe an experiment and another user (@Justme) has rightly pointed out that this is bad engineering: using a component outside its rated specifications. I understand you have supply problems but accepting this answer yourself doesn't make this a solution that others can reliably refer to.

Comment: Dharmik - Hi, The site allows self-answers to be "áccepted" by the OP (i.e. you). If there are problems with that answer, you may see downvotes or comments explaining them. Although people are allowed to edit an answer (even a self-answer) to improve it, this site is not a blog and shouldn't be treated like one. || If you are not *sure* that this is the correct solution to your question, then perhaps you posted this as an answer a bit prematurely? Or, if you *are* sure, then there is no need for updates. || If you have *improvements* to your answer (not blog-like updates) you can edit it.

Comment: The IC that I used is rated up to 7V yes I do accept that it can perform optimally under 3.6V but I wanted to test what happens if I use it for 5V and whether this IC can provide sufficient conversion speed for the WS2812b LED strip. 
And one more thing I did not test only 1 IC, I tested 10IC with different circuits and all worked perfectly fine with WS2812b It was installed successfully in my House and working fine.  So I believe the datasheet it can stand up to 7V and if can reduce performance after 3.6v but its more than enough needed for WS2812b.